# Running two node servers from a single shell command using a shell script

Tags: node.js, unix, webserver

I have to run two node servers in different port, I want to write a simple shell script that will start both of the servers.

I wrote it like below:

```
node project/rest.js && node static-server.js
```

but when I run the commands at a time, it starts the first server and dont execute the second one.

And only the fist server listens for request, second static server doesn't start. And in the shell I do have a output from rest.js.

What I previously did to run tow servers, I run two commands in different shell.

Is there a way I can run both of the server with a single shell script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also.. "Forever" might be of interest to you.. https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Answer (score 31):

Your command does not work because you are trying to have two processes running in the same shell. Instead, you should 'spawn' the node processes into different processes. Try this command:

```
node project/rest.js & node static-server.js &
```

Comment: i place all the three server in `app.js` file and run with `node app.js > app.js.log`. And its working fine. How can i keep log for each server separately?

Comment: @m2j So you have 3 servers being started in the same process? You can't keep logs separately using a command. You would have to specify the log file for each server inside your `app.js`

Comment: This doesn't work if you have two separate node projects in different directories.

Comment: @VladyVeselinov Why not?

Answer (score 1):

i have written very simple shell script, for starting MongoDB, start multiple node servers in a new terminal window and open Webstorm Ide.

it uses https://github.com/mklement0/ttab library, for opening new terminal windows.

you can specify multiple projects in code and with simple if else
or maybe with switch statement, differentiate projects.

```
sh dev.sh waufwauf
```

will cd and start waufwauf project, hope it helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "waufwauf" ]
then
  cd Code/waufwauf;
    ttab -d ./ mongod;
    ttab -d server npm run dev;
    ttab -d client npm run dev;
    wstorm ~/Code/waufwauf;
elif [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo specify project name;  
else
    echo $1 unknown project;
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, this will work,

start node project/rest.js && start node static-server.js

Comment: what tool is this start command ? on what OS ? This doesn't seem to be installed by default on ubuntu 18.10